How to add a collator in backstage new backend system
I'm trying to add my custom collator to search on the new backend system of backstage but I'm facing a hard time in doing so. Can somebody point me to the right resources or how to do it?
I created a backend-plugin using backstage-cli and created a collator. How to use the collator within the plugin
Collator.ts
import { Logger } from 'winston';
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import { DocumentCollatorFactory } from '@backstage/plugin-search-common'
import { IndianCitiesDocument } from './document';
import { Permission } from '@backstage/plugin-permission-common';
import { resolvePackagePath } from '@backstage/backend-common';

export type CollatorFactoryOptions = {
    logger: Logger
}

export class CollatorFactory implements DocumentCollatorFactory{
    private readonly baseUrl: string | undefined
    private readonly logger: Logger;
    public readonly type: string = 'my-awesome-plugin';
    private constructor(options: CollatorFactoryOptions){
        this.logger = options.logger;
    }
    visibilityPermission?: Permission | undefined;

    static fromConfig(options:CollatorFactoryOptions){
        return new CollatorFactory({ ...options})
    }

    async getCollator(){
        return Readable.from(this.execute())
    }

    async *execute(): AsyncGenerator<IndianCitiesDocument>{
        this.logger.info('Inside execute function')
        const packagePath = resolvePackagePath("@internal/backstage-plugin-my-awesome-plugin-backend")
        this.logger.info(packagePath)
        // const data = await response.json()
    }
}


plugin.ts
import {
  coreServices,
  createBackendPlugin,
} from '@backstage/backend-plugin-api';
import { createRouter } from './service/router';

/**
 * myTestPlugin backend plugin
 *
 * @public
 */
export const myTestPlugin = createBackendPlugin({
  pluginId: 'my-test',
  register(env) {
    env.registerInit({
      deps: {
        httpRouter: coreServices.httpRouter,
        logger: coreServices.logger,
      },
      async init({
        httpRouter,
        logger,
      }) {
        httpRouter.use(
          await createRouter({
            logger,
          }),
        );
        httpRouter.addAuthPolicy({
          path: '/health',
          allow: 'unauthenticated',
        });
      },
    });
  },
});


backend is the latest backend by backstage and i'm directly importing and adding the file
backend/src/index.ts
/*
 * Hi!
 *
 * Note that this is an EXAMPLE Backstage backend. Please check the README.
 *
 * Happy hacking!
 */

import { createBackend } from '@backstage/backend-defaults';

const backend = createBackend();

backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-app-backend/alpha'));
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-proxy-backend/alpha'));
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-scaffolder-backend/alpha'));
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-techdocs-backend/alpha'));

// auth plugin
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-auth-backend'));
// See https://backstage.io/docs/backend-system/building-backends/migrating#the-auth-plugin
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-auth-backend-module-guest-provider'));
// See https://backstage.io/docs/auth/guest/provider

// catalog plugin
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend/alpha'));
backend.add(
  import('@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend-module-scaffolder-entity-model'),
);

// permission plugin
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-permission-backend/alpha'));
backend.add(
  import('@backstage/plugin-permission-backend-module-allow-all-policy'),
);

// search plugin
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-search-backend/alpha'));
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-search-backend-module-catalog/alpha'));
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-search-backend-module-techdocs/alpha'));

// my plugins
backend.add(import('@internal/backstage-plugin-my-awesome-plugin-backend'))
backend.add(import('@internal/backstage-plugin-my-test-backend'))

backend.start();


Follow up : I have indices residing in opensearch whose data I want to use for search. Can I directly use these indices for search? What should be the approach? Again any resources on the same would help.

Figured it out. Instead of creating a backend plugin create a backend-module where pluginId is search as we are going to add a functionality to existing search plugin by adding a collator and then within the module file we can add the logic to use the collator as before. This module can then directly be imported into the backstage backend
